# Login User On Cross Domain Using Ajax Call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, session, authentication, cors

We are facing a very strange issue. What I need is to Login user on Cross domain which is hosted on a separate server using ajax.

**CORS** is enabled on destination server and request to login page sends back a success response; but when I redirect after success the browser does not recognize the session and redirects to **login page** again.

Following is my ajax call

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: Url,
            data: Data,
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type' : "application/json",
                'Accept': "application/json"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                window.location = "https://destination-domain";
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
```

Is it possible to send a post request and Login user on another domain where CORS is enabled?

Comment: We can post data where CORS is enabled.

Comment: Yes we can, but to login we need to maintain a session which browser does not allow.

Answer (score 1):

Cross domain login will not be possible, and you have to go with less secure solution like JSONP GET request to login user